# Remove or hide a menu item in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo

I have this menu item, and I want to hide or remove it.

[image]

Comment: applye techinical rights then after go on 
user interface >> menu item

Comment: i wanted to do with code i have rights f technical

Answer (score 17):

First create a dummy group with no users in it

```
<record id="make_invisible" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Invisible</field>
 </record>
```

Replace all users in the group. The `eval` statement here means, replace all ids in the `groups_id` field with the id for group `make_invisible`.

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="module.menu_name">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,[ref('make_invisible')])]"/>
</record>
```

You can find more information on how the eval works [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-4-in-the-expression-eval-4-ref-base-group-user-84907)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and provide some additional information as to why this is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

No need to create a group and assign a group to the menu. You can simply make the menu inactive by setting menu `active="False"`. Here is an example,

```
<menuitem id="module.menu_id" active="False"/>
```

Comment: This works in odoo14. Better solution than the highest voted answer in my opinion.

Comment: I just tested it in Odoo v16 and it still works like charm. Thanks a lot, poster!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide it, go to the views section of your module, find that item and edit your list of groups with users, able to see it. For example, one of my menu items down below:

```
 <menuitem id="tabel_menu_emp_by_division" name="Employees by division"
              parent="tabel_menu"
              action="tabel_list_emp_action_group_by_division"  sequence="5" groups="Tabel.group_manager,Tabel.group_accountant,Tabel.group_eco"/>
```

As we can see, only listed groups (Tabel.group_manager,Tabel.group_accountant,Tabel.group_eco) can see that menu item.

If you want to remove it, just delete it from the views section.

Answer (score 3):

if it has no sub-menus you can reuse it with your own action and name and parent

```
    <menuitem id="module.old_menu_id" name="your string here" parent="your_parent_menu_id" 
action="your_action_id" 
sequence="10" 
groups="your_groups_here"/>
```

with this way it will hide from its location and appear in your parent menu with your action

Answer (score 1):

Create a new group with no users in it and assign the menu item to this group.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution with no group then try `active="false"` after overriding the `menuitem`.