# Why do we have to create a new group to hide a menuitem from all users in Odoo v8?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I was just wondering why we have to apply this solution to hide an existing menuitem from all users (administrator with technical features included):

[Remove or hide a menu item in Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908406/remove-or-hide-a-menu-item-in-odoo)

I mean, can anyone explain me why this does not work?

```
<record id="stock_account.menu_action_history_tree" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [])]"/>
</record>
```

After this, if I go to the interface and check this menuitem record in the technical features section, I can see that the `groups_id` many2many list is empty. So, why is the administrator still able to see it?

Comment: Why adding a menu item that nobody can see? Can't you just remove it?

Comment: @Yajo the menuitem already exists, I need to hide it. And using `delete` tag is not very safe as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to make action false to hide the menutitem,
This helps

```
<record id="stock_account.menu_action_history_tree" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="action" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

Comment: That works and it is what I was trying to do, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If `groups_id` field is empty, Odoo will compute visibility based on the related object's read access.

You can find this help at [**addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py**](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_menu.py#L429).

> > 'groups_id': fields.many2many('res.groups', 'ir_ui_menu_group_rel',
> >                 'menu_id', 'gid', 'Groups', help="If you have groups, the visibility of this menu will be based on these groups. "\
> >                     "If this field is empty, Odoo will compute visibility based on the related object's read access."),

Comment: That's a great answer Wako, it solves my question, but I'm giving you only +1 because @khelili's answer works and makes what I need (hiding an option without creating an auxiliar security group). Thank you!